# IPS test using the plm R package gives different T-rho values from individually pefromed ADF test statistics

Tags: r, statistics, panel, plm, ips

I have been throught the Im, Pesaran and Shin paper many times to solve this issue but have failed so far.
When I perform the IPS test in R using the `plm` package [`purtest()` function] I get exactly the same rho values for every panel as when I do the ADF test individually for it, but the problem is that the T-rho individual statistic differs. Shouldn't it be the same with ADF test?

Since I do have the same rho coefficient value I understand that the difference should be coming from the rho coefficient's standard error.

I use same lags and intercept as an exogenous variable at both tests.

Has anyone encountered this before?

As you see to a simple example with one only panel below (same happens with multiple panels), IPS rho value is equal to the ADF z.lag.1 Estimate ( -0.376026893)

However, IPS trho = -3.6235638, while ADF t-statistic is -3.5532

Why is this difference?

```
Im-Pesaran-Shin Unit-Root Test

Exogenous variables: Individual Intercepts
Automatic selection of lags using AIC: 0 - 0 lags (max: 5)

statistic (Wtbar): -2.41   
p-value: 0.008

          lags obs          rho         trho         p.trho         mean    var

Section1    0  52      -0.376026893  -3.6235638   0.005353902223  -1.5254  0.7578


###############################################
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test #
###############################################
    
Test regression drift

Call:    
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1)

Residuals:
        Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max

-0.51672098 -0.13117631 -0.02416759  0.09858407  0.47207489

Coefficients:

               Estimate  Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)   

(Intercept) -0.00638350  0.02452175 -0.26032 0.79568610       
z.lag.1     -0.37602689  0.10582777 -3.55320 0.00084152 ***
---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1768252 on 50 degrees of freedom

Multiple R-squared:  0.2015994, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1856314

F-statistic: 12.62521 on 1 and 50 DF,  p-value: 0.0008415186

Value of test-statistic is: -3.5532 6.3408

Critical values for test statistics:
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.51 -2.89 -2.58    
phi1  6.70  4.71  3.86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statistical tests come with a lot of parameters to specify. Your observation seems to relate to the parameter `dfcor` to `purtest`.

See this example where `rho` is the same no matter the value for `dfcor` but `trho` is slightly different:

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld)
pG <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld)
b  <- purtest(pG$value, test = "ips", exo = "intercept", lags = 0, dfcor = TRUE)
b2 <- purtest(pG$value, test = "ips", exo = "intercept", lags = 0, dfcor = FALSE)
summary(b)
#> Im-Pesaran-Shin Unit-Root Test 
#> Exogenous variables: Individual Intercepts 
#> User-provided lags
#> statistic (Wtbar): -1.419 
#> p-value: 0.078 
#> 
#>    lags obs        rho       trho       p.trho    mean    var
#> 1     0  19 -0.7221173 -3.0980241 0.0267255342 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 2     0  19 -0.8376784 -3.9708351 0.0015756584 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 3     0  19 -0.5503275 -2.4918122 0.1174272537 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 4     0  19 -0.9812049 -4.4232340 0.0002648235 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 5     0  19 -0.0246934 -0.2247631 0.9329996429 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 6     0  19  0.1313902  2.0376353 0.9999127394 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 7     0  19 -0.2767321 -1.5074566 0.5300598000 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 8     0  19 -0.2343526 -1.4013933 0.5833071748 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 9     0  19 -0.3064189 -1.4852375 0.5413593097 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 10    0  19 -0.6898608 -2.8137835 0.0562945264 -1.5204 0.8654

summary(b2)
#> Im-Pesaran-Shin Unit-Root Test 
#> Exogenous variables: Individual Intercepts 
#> User-provided lags
#> statistic (Wtbar): -1.796 
#> p-value: 0.036 
#> 
#>    lags obs        rho       trho       p.trho    mean    var
#> 1     0  19 -0.7221173 -3.2751947 1.605723e-02 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 2     0  19 -0.8376784 -4.1979203 6.603715e-04 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 3     0  19 -0.5503275 -2.6343147 8.602350e-02 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 4     0  19 -0.9812049 -4.6761911 8.947014e-05 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 5     0  19 -0.0246934 -0.2376169 9.313144e-01 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 6     0  19  0.1313902  2.1541642 9.999458e-01 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 7     0  19 -0.2767321 -1.5936655 4.858266e-01 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 8     0  19 -0.2343526 -1.4815366 5.432370e-01 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 9     0  19 -0.3064189 -1.5701756 4.979070e-01 -1.5204 0.8654
#> 10    0  19 -0.6898608 -2.9746990 3.733484e-02 -1.5204 0.8654
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thnk it makes sense when the individual time series have small number of points to compute the ADF regression slope standard error without a degrees-of-freedom correction.